# How to pass Optional-Positional arguments to a function in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I am trying to understand the usage of positional arguments in MATLAB and I was referring to [this](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/parse-function-inputs.html) page.

Let's say I have a MATLAB function defined as follows:

```
function printPhoto(filename,varargin)
    p = inputParser;
    defaultFinish = 'glossy';
    validFinishes = {'glossy','matte', 'colorful'};
    checkFinish = @(x) any(validatestring(x,validFinishes));

    defaultColor = 'RGB';
    validColors = {'RGB','CMYK','colorful'};
    checkColor = @(x) any(validatestring(x,validColors));

    defaultWidth = 6;
    defaultHeight = 4;

    addRequired(p,'filename',@ischar);
    addOptional(p,'finish',defaultFinish,checkFinish);
    addOptional(p,'color',defaultColor,checkColor);
    addParameter(p,'width',defaultWidth,@isnumeric);
    addParameter(p,'height',defaultHeight,@isnumeric);
    parse(p,filename,varargin{:});
end
```

When I call the above function as follows: `printphoto('myFile.img', 'colorful')`, is it possible to make this second argument to correspond to the second optional positional argument in the function definition i.e. `color='colorful'` and not `finish='colorful'`?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you get when mixing optional-positional arguments and parameters. *IMHO*, you should use **one or the other, but not both**.

When you define an argument as positional, you're telling MATLAB that this input will **always** appear in that specific place, *if it does appear*. If you want to play around with the order of the inputs, that's exactly what a parameter-type argument is for.

Just think about it, the following syntaxes aren't that different:

```
printphoto('myFile.img','color','colorful')
printphoto('myFile.img', color='colorful' )
```

So I would suggest sticking with parameter-type arguments, but if you insist on having them positional, make sure that you assign a default value to the input if the user wants to "skip" it (by supplying some agreed-upon "null" value such as `""` or `[]`).

Comment: many functions have both and it is often convenient, but the bottom line is correct, call printphoto('myFile.img',[], 'colorful')

Comment: @Yuval I agree it can be useful. I merely meant that once you decide on an API (be it positional, having parameters or a mix thereof) you should stick with it, and not expect it to suddenly work differently. It appears that the OP wants to force positional arguments to behave like parameters - which indicated bad design (since if this is an anticipated use-case, they have no reason for being positional in the first place).